# By what in-game logic is there no market for wizard spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, content-identification, economy

Finally, the equipment tables make no mention of spell scrolls, so they cannot be bought by default.

The ***real reason*** magic items and spells cannot be bought by default is of course that D&D is an adventure game, not a market simulation.

> Magic items are gleaned from the hoards of conquered monsters or discovered in long-lost vaults. (*DMG p. 135*)

Finding scrolls and winning spell books from evil wizards (or salvaging them from their tombs) is a great incentive for wizard character players to go adventuring. It rewards them with new powers for the risks they are taking.

There is also accepted precedent that [the game intends for wizards to be unwilling to share their magic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67609/what-is-the-role-play-justification-for-named-wizard-spells?rq=1).

This however seems inconsistent with other assumptions in the core rules:

#### Spellcasting Services

> Hiring someone to cast a relatively common spell of 1st or 2nd level, such as cure wounds or identify, is easy enough in a city or town, and might cost 10 to 50 gold pieces (plus the cost of any expensive material components). (*p. 159 PHB*)

This indicates wizards of up to 3rd level are easily found in cities and towns, and that they are willing in principle to provide their abilities in exchange for gold.

Even higher level spells may be obtained. The description indicates that pure finanical payment may be insufficient for those:

> Finding someone able and willing to cast a higher-level spell might involve traveling to a large city, perhaps one with a university or prominent temple. Once found, the spellcaster might ask for a service instead of payment—the kind of service that only adventurers can provide.

#### Scrolls

Wizards able to cast 2nd level spells also would be able to craft common items such as cantrips or first level scrolls.

Even Adventurer's Leage [allows scribing of scrolls](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116669/is-crafting-scrolls-allowed-during-downtime-for-adventurers-league-characters/142985#142985), for PCs, and if PCs can do so certainly NPC wizards can do likewise. That

> Even uncommon items can't be easily created. (p. 135 DMG)

is certainly not true for spell scrolls.

And while the core crafting system makes it [more costly to write scrolls than what their gp value is](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60478/do-magic-items-really-cost-at-least-as-much-to-create-as-they-do-to-purchase), player character wizards would often be willing to pay a higher price for access to new spells for leftover [useless gold](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47604/without-a-magic-item-economy-what-is-gold-for?noredirect=1&lq=1).

#### Spellbook copying

Even worse, between two wizards there is NO NEED to engage in costly scroll crafting to trade spells. They can just copy them from each other's spellbooks for free to both increase their arsenal (except for the cost for ink that you always have -- it costs nothing to get access to the spell).

There is really little that my groups' wizard player characters would like better than copying new spells in town, for payment, or even better for lettimg the town mage copy some of theirs, which would cost them nothing. Every new town the first stop is the town mage to see if he has any spells to sell or copy.

If it is so desirable for PC wizards, why would NPC wizards not have the same compulsion?

Why are there no spell trading fairs? After all, knowledge only grows when it is shared, to the benefit of all involved.

Spells should be on sale in *some form* in a world where wizards are relatively common.

By what in-game logic is there no market for wizard spells?

Comment: What rule says that it's impossible to share spells with other Wizards? Or are you basing it on just the lack of a simple table with costs per spell/level/school/whatever? I'd say the rules are pretty clear that you *can* copy spells if someone lets you; whether someone lets you is based on the world you're living in.

Comment: @erik: I do not really see this in any of the published adventures. The closest I found is the example I cite from Dragon Heist.

Comment: "Why do you not see this in published adventures" is a very different question, that might have more to do with published adventure design.

Comment: @Erik, if what you say is that the answer is this is possible, I think this would be an answer to best be put into an actual answer (https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133804/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-groody-the-hobgoblin).

Comment: You answered your own question at the beginning *D&D is an adventure game, not a market simulation* Given that each DM will make more or fewer items available for sale (IME) based on how they want their world to work, your presumption of a standard structure like that is false, or invalid, assumption around which to build a question.

Comment: If you tag this question as lore and pick a particular setting like forgotten realms, it might be answered.

Comment: If you're working on getting this question re-opened, you might want to factor in the idea that the RAW game is the template that is being provided to GMs, GMs then make individual campaigns.  Individual GMs can make provisions for copying and not only are they completely within RAW, that's really their job.  PC: "I try to find a like-minded wizard that would trade spells."  It's then the GM's job to decide how that plays out.  Maybe it works out great, maybe the locals shut that down right quick, maybe hi-jinks ensue.  That is completely RAW.

Comment: I think this is definitely a question this community can answer. Many of us here are very experienced DMs who have created countless homebrew worlds. I am positive that Groody and I are not the only people to ever think about this question. I know I have in world justification in my games as to why spells aren't freely, or at least openly, shared. I doubt I am some exceptional GM in this regard, I am certain that this community has the expertise to answer this question. I don't see why it should be closed.

Comment: this question appears to be a combination of 'why don't the rules list this' and 'what are some reasons why X might Y in my world setting?'.  both are valid questions, but i've only answered the first.  not sure the second is meant t obe in there.  but if it is, maybe ask it separately.

Comment: This argument/rant doesn't fit our Q&A style — consider using a forum: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it either asks for designer reasons or is primarily-opinion-based. The recent answer explicitly makes assumptions about the designers' intentions *and* explains that it had to refrain from giving opinion answers

Comment: I think you need to open a new quetion and re-phrase. It is possible to answer a question that look at the history of approaches in D&D for wizards' (or mages') magic. It just takes a little digging through the rulebooks to pin-point the variations throughout.

Comment: For what it's worth, I feel like this can be answered based on the downtime rules in XGE, which discuss both the market for magic items and the factors that go into making spell scrolls. Combining those two gives a pretty solid RAW explanation of how a wizard could purchase a copy of a new spell and what would make it easier or harder to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Magic Item Shoppes

5th Edition D&D's various rulebooks both make mention of magic items for sale (such as in Waterdeep in the Forgotten Realms) and vaguely discourage making magic items available for sale as a GM, in a few different ways.

Why this is this way is a complicated question involving previous editions of D&D, player expectations, GM laziness, solutions used in other ttrpgs, but can be largely boiled down to that 5e's design is largely intentionally vague - they wanted Wealth-By-Level and spiraling GP costs gone, but also not to offend or annoy anyone who liked playing Dungeons and Shopping Trips, so they vaguely said 'don't do this' but not very strongly and left it fairly open to people still allowing magic items to be bought for money.

Like most of 5e's rules design, there is no real in-game logic.  Many things don't make sense if you invoke that dread god Physics, much less their siblings - Economics, Biology, or (gasp) *Sociology*.

Spells therefore have no listed price to be cast on your behalf (or copied), which they have had in previous editions, largely due to this expelling of WBL and decoupling of gold from 'power'.

**Is there an in-universe explanation for why there would be no generally acceptable rate of exchange for copying spells or buying spell scrolls?**  Sure.  There's probably dozens.  Ask any GM and they likely will come up with some reason, or just have spells often traded in their world instead.  I had to resist the urge to list a half-dozen just now, because after a while world-building gets ingrained in the bone.  But those in-universe reasons will differ from table to table, and I've seen no official party line on the subject - just a few scattered tweets that seem to be just 'GM makes up some stuff' answers themselves.

The actual reason the rules don't list prices for spells, copying spells, or spell scrolls is because of complaints about Wealth-By-Level systems and 5e's general design philosophy of going back to the simpler (and vaguer) 'GM makes it up' rules like those in 2e.  Spells = magic, magic = magic items, magic items = no prices, is probably the thought process (if any).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful perpective about the design process (and politics) of 5e. Just one small comment, while 1e and 2e actively advised against that magic items could be simply bought, they *did* have individual prices for all of the magic items, which incidentially made it a lot easier to compare relative power or cost out crafting in a reasonable way, than what 5e offers.

Comment: Also, why go adventuring to find spells and arcane magic if you can just buy them at the local shop.  The whole point of the PC is to **Adventure** (Nice answer)

Comment: Ed Greenwood has commented that for FR the amount of interesting magical items produced (eg not healing potions) are in the hundreds per year, because wizards are not industrial producers. He's also said that buying or selling magical items in a big city like Waterdeep isn't that hard, but should still be a role playing experience, eg not a simple shop.